# An IVP with 'dummy' singularity

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

Suppose we are given a first order IVP:
$$ (1-x)y' = (1-x)y, \quad y(0) = 1 . $$

If one is asked to find the largest interval $I$ so that the solutions is defined, should one answer $ I = (-\infty, 1) $ or $ I = (-\infty,\infty) = \mathbb{R} $?

I think the answer is $ I = (-\infty, 1) $ because anyway $x=1$ is a singularity of the equation so the solution can be defined only in either $(-\infty, 1)$ or $(1,\infty)$ according to the initial value.

I'd appreciate it to any explanation on this. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  The function $y(x)=e^x$ satisfies the ODE for all values of $t\in\mathbb{R}$, in particular for $t=1$.

Comment: @user539887 Yes it is, but isn't it also true that the solution to an IVP is well-defined only in the interval without singularity?

Comment: It depends on the definition. I took the most obvious one: a function satisfies (or, if you prefer, is a solution of) a differential equation if for each value in the domain of the function the differential equation holds.  And such is the case for $t=1$: the LHS is $(1-1) e^1=0$ and the RHS is $(1-1) e^1=0$.

Comment: @user539887 Thank you for your kind explanations. I think I understand it for this particular problem. What if we have an IVP that is not well-defined for some values of $x$, e.g. $y′+(\tan x) \cdot y=\cos^2 x, \quad y(0)=1$? We cannot evaluate the value of the LHS for $x = (2n+1)\pi/2$, but $ y = \cos x \sin x + \cos x $ satisfies the DE. Can we say the solution is well-defined on the whole real line?

Comment: Actually this was my original question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3147887/an-ivp-with-singularity-having-continuous-solutions
and I was trying to simplify the DE to have a singularity but also to have a regular solution.

Comment: I commented below your second question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the function $$f(a,b,c,x):=\begin{cases}a\cdot e^x & x<1\\b & x=1\\c\cdot e^x & x>1,\end{cases}$$ and suppose $F(x)=f(a,b,c,x)$ for some $a,b,c\in\Bbb R.$ Here are some facts about $F$ that I leave to you to verify:

- $F:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R.$
- $F$ is continuous(ly differentiable) on $\Bbb R$ if and only if $a=b=c.$
- $y=F(x)$ is a solution to the IVP if and only if $a=1.$

So, we certainly don't have uniqueness outside the interval $(-\infty,1).$ The only everywhere-differentiable solution is $y=e^x,$ and all solutions agree with it on $(-\infty,1),$ but (unless we impose further restrictions on our solutions) need not agree with it anywhere else.

Comment: If $a=b=c$ does not hold then $F'(1)$ is **undefined**. And the result of multiplying zero by something undefined is undefined, not zero.  So, under the natural interpretation of the term "solution", such an $F$ is not a solution.  When one admits solutions satisfying the equation a.e., then yes, there are many solutions, but I doubt if that was the OP's intention.

Comment: I see your point, but I'm not sure I agree. Consider the IVP $xy'+2y=0,$ $y(1)=1.$ Would you say it has no solution? Would you say that $y=\frac1{x^2}$ is a solution, even though $y'(0)$ is undefined?

Comment: In this case I would say that $y=\frac1{x^2}$ is a solution defined on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: I would agree that it is a solution, though it's defined on more than just $(0,\infty).$ In fact, for any constant $c,$ I would say that $$f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac1{x^2} & x>0\\\frac{c}{x^2} & x<0\end{cases}$$ is a solution with the same domain of definition. Of course, they all agree on $(0,\infty),$ which means that our solutions have uniquely-defined behavior on $(0,\infty),$ but that doesn't mean they don't exist anywhere else, nor do they fail to be solutions simply by virtue of failing to be differentiable everywhere. Would you agree?

Comment: I remember a discussion somewhere on MSE about a similar thing.  The OP asked about why a solution of an **IVP** cannot be defined on a disjoint union of two intervals.  The most upvoted answer (with which I fully agree) was that then one would lose the uniqueness.  I am sorry that I cannot find it.

Comment: No worries! I agree: the domain of uniqueness is of great importance.

Comment: Many thanks to both of you for the discussion. It helped a lot.